# Select rows with max date hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to write a criteria query for selecting rows with max date:

```
Criteria criteria;

//getting criteria

criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.date = (__QUERY_FOR_MAX_DATE__)"));
```

Is it possible to avoid writting sqlRestriction derictly and do it merely with Criteria query?

I mean applying some projections, or something similar... Without writing the sql-restriction explcicitly.

Comment: What is 'QUERY_FOR_MAX_DATE'? Is it from same table or from different table

Comment: Use DetachedCriteria

Comment: @Arjit From the same table. The date is a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria innerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ClassName.class, "inner")
                                  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.max("inner.dateColumnName")));

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ClassName.class, "outer");
crit.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("outer.dateColumnName", innerCriteria));
```